# git: checking merge conflicts WITHOUT actually doing the merge

Tags: git

Can't find the answer to this precise question via googling.

I do normal merge, say `git merge origin/master`. Say some conflicts are created.

I do not want that. I would like to just check, see the possible conflicts, in terms of files, commits, and diffs *without* starting the merge process.

Sure, I can do `git reset --hard`. Rather drastic for just seeing potential conflicts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option

Answer (score 2):

Merging is not "just merging". You can choose different strategies to merge branches, and I'm afraid that the git is unable to predict (figure out) conflicts before the branches are actually merged. Hypothetically, without running merging process, you could only get information that there is "just conflict" somewhere. "Just conflict" is not valuable information (you write that you want to see files with conflicts, commits etc.). So, there is no "just check". But 3-step solution is really simple in fact.

As in the answer Lacek points you to:

1. merge without commit and fast-forward

   $ git merge --no-commit --no-ff <branch_to_be_merge>

Without `commit` you do not have to `reset --hard` it :-)

`ff` is a special case of merging - as git documentation states - when possible it only updates the branch pointer to match the merged branch and do not create a merge commit, so the `--no-commit` option does not protect against `fast-forward`.

2. check if there are any conflicts and if so, check the conflicting files

Message after merge will tell you if there is "just conflict". But at that point you can examine conflicts more deeply. Of course `git diff --cached` mentioned in the answer from the link, and `git status` will show you which files have conflicts. As the merging process inserts 'points of failure' into the files you can see them with `git diff` or review them manually. Also `git log --merge` is your friend. This way, you will gain valuable and actionable insights regarding conflicts.

3. undo changes and clean up the mess

   $ git merge --abort

This should reconstruct the pre-merge state. In fact it makes `git reset --merge`, so resets 'MERGE_HEAD', but also applies the merge auto stash entry to the worktree if merge was invoked with `--autostash` option on a dirty tree.

Take a look at the git-merge documentation for all the options mentioned above https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: This is also what I currently do, but the problem is that you lose the conflict information after doing `git merge --abort`. So you end up doing lots of back-and-forths to resolve the conflicts one by one. Do you have any tips for this?

Comment: Maybe a branch dedicated to save the snapshot of the conflict? An idea - a little bit tested: Let's say on the master you see the conflict, so you make `--abort`, then
`git checkout -b tst-merge`;
`git merge --no-commit --no-ff origin/master`;
`git status` ("On branch tst-merge... both modified: test.txt");
`git add test.txt`;
`git commit -m "Save conflict"`;
`git checkout master`;
`git diff master tst-merge`.